# How to export Lucidworks Fusion index with full text

Tags: solr, export, full-text-search, fusion, lucidworks

Im looking to export the metadata and the page contents that is being full text indexed and stored in Fusion index. I see there is no direct API available to query the entire content of each record other than for metadata. I believe accessing this via SOLR is restricted. Can someone advise on any solution approaches here?

I tried reviewing doc.Lucidworks.com to see if there is an API available. The metadata attribute’body’ doesn’t seems to show entire content in the response.